# JQuery/Javascript simple div slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a simple animation i'm trying to make. The divs array carries the id of different divs. The loop function simply loops through the array and shows the divs and hides them making it like a slideshow. For some reason, both divs show at the same time and then hide at the same time. I just couldn't figure out why...please help out! Thanks!

**Edit:I think the javascript loop isn't waiting for the JQuery animation to finish. I think ill have to use the setInterval function? Can someone tell me how I can use it here?**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var divs=["#slide1","#slide2"];

function loop(){
for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
{
    $(divs[i]).show(1000).hide(1000);
}
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#slide1").show();
    loop();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slide1" style="display:none">ONE</div>
<div id="slide2" style="display:none">TWO</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ngGbF/)**

```
var divs = ["#slide1", "#slide2"];
function loop() {
    var elem = divs.shift();
    $(elem).show(1000).hide(1000, function () {
        divs.push(elem);
        loop();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#slide1").show();
    loop();
});
```